# Are safari extensions subject to CSP?

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I was making a safari extension which injects iframes into webpages. On doing so, I came across an error. On some webpages, I get an error,

> Refused to frame 'safari-extension://abcdefgh/hello.html' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src https: twitter:".

I guess that this happens because safari extensions are subject to CSP. However, the same error is not seen in chrome extension when the iframe.src is set to a local file packaged in the extension.

How can I resolve this issue? Also, does this have to do only with content-security-policy but also with X-Frame-Options?

Comment: Hi, did you come across any solution / reasonable workaround?